# Checking the element whether it is in array and getting remaining values of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array(1,3,5,7,10) and an variable containing value say a=1 Now i want to get the result as array(3,5,7,10) ie. getting the values other than that variable value

Answer (score 3):

```
array_diff($original_array, array($a));
```

Answer (score 2):

use array_diff: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

```
$arr1 = array(1,3,5,7,10)
$a = 1
$arr2 = array_diff($arr1, array($a))
```